# Xamarin Android tabbed page, tab title doesn't match with page content

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, tabbedpage

I am using Xamarin to implementing an APP.

While using tabbed page with 6 sheet.

Follow the step below:

1. Go to 2nd sheet.
2. Click the 5th tab on the top bar.(The 5th page takes few second to load. So the page didn't change to 5th page immediately)
3. (Instantly after step 2)Click anywhere of the page content below(At this step. The page hasn't changed to 5th tab yet.

Normally I think the result should be: The top tab bar stop at 5th. And the page content changed to 5th page too.

But my result is: After these step. The top tab bar would stop at 5th. But the page content would stay at 2nd page.

How should I avoid this?

Thank you!

Comment: I was not able to reproduce this issue with tabbedpage. Could you provide more details for this?

Comment: Hi Wendy, at my case. The 5th tab take few seconds to load. So after press the tab. It won't change immediately. Before it change. I press the content of 2nd page.

Maybe the loading time would be a critical part of this issue.

Comment: Maybe you could use some tips to reduce the loading time of the 5th page like load local content, reduce number of assemblies and so on. For more tips, check the blog. https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/5-ways-boost-xamarin-forms-app-startup-time/